# Embedded AVplayer does not play videos from URL, Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, avplayerviewcontroller

I'm trying to code a basic app that presents videos in a list and then plays them using AVplayer from URLS in a database. The video just displays a blank screen with the player controls and does not play the video or show any info. I have tried multiple different links from youtube, vimeo and filesharing sites, all with the same problem, all links are https/

Here is the code I'm using

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import SwiftUI

struct VideoPlayerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var videoURL: URL
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {
        // Do nothing
    }
}

struct VideoDetailView: View {
    var video: Video
    
    var body: some View{
        VStack (spacing: 20){
            Spacer()
            
            Image(video.imageName)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(height: 150)
                .cornerRadius(12)
            
            Text(video.title)
                .font(.title2)
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .lineLimit(2)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .padding(.horizontal)
            
            HStack(spacing: 40) {
                Label("\(video.viewCount)", systemImage: "eye.fill")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                
                Text (video.uploadDate)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            }
            
            Text(video.description)
                .font(.body)
                .padding()
            
            Spacer()
            
            NavigationLink(destination: VideoPlayerView(videoURL: video.url)) {
                Label("Play Video", systemImage: "play.circle.fill")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Tried different links, different file formats all https.

Video doesnt play just shows player controls or play button with a slash through in simulator.

Comment: Can you share an example of a link that doesn't work? Are you sure the file is in a format readable to `AVPlayer`?

Comment: @jnpdx  Thanks for replying, I'm not sure I'm very new to this,
here is an example of the view that contains the links,


struct VideoList {
    
    static let topTen = [
        Video(imageName: "Rhythm",
              title: "Rhythm",
              description: "In this video we learn the basics of rhythm with Stuart on garageband!",
              viewCount: 370222,
              uploadDate: "February 17, 2019",
              url: URL(string: "https://youtu.be/UZ2EJfsAW8k")!),

Comment: I also tried this type of URL from Vimeo,   https://vimeo.com/445519785?share=copy

Comment: Those links will definitely not work -- you need to provide actual links to the media files themselves -- not just websites that have the videos embedded.

Comment: ok cool, so if I provide a link to a file on a hosting site it can work, or do the files have to be stored locally? I know I can do this with local files, but wanted them to be from some kind of remote site where the videos are hosted. Thanks for your help!

Comment: They can be hosted remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the conversation in the comments, and the URL you said you're trying to access: those URLs won't work. YouTube, Vimeo, and (most) File Sharing sites do *not* provide direct access to files without a bit of extra work.

The `AVPlayer` initializer you're using expects a valid URL pointing to a properly encoded video **file**. [avplayer](/questions/tagged/avplayer) won't do the work of getting the actual video file for you from those URLs.

You can better understand the problem here by looking at what the network returns from a URL. For example, the URL you posted, `https://vimeo.com/445519785?share=copy`, returns HTML content to load a webpage. `AVPlayer` doesn't understand that, so will fail to load anything.

So, instead of passing in something like this to `AVPlayer`:

```swift
AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://vimeo.com/someVideo")!)
```

You'll need to pass in a properly formatted URL pointing to a video file:

```swift
AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://vimeo.com/someVideo/downloadPath/file.mov")!)
```

How you get those URLs is beyond the scope of this particular question.

*But, I will say that if this is your video (you own it / uploaded it), you should be able to get the direct download URL from the video management page on Vimeo.*